# UI is not updating in Angular 2

Tags: angular2-services

After getting notifications from Firebase I want to update my `orderlists`. For that I am invoking `OrderRequest()` inside other Component (using @ViewChild). In Console I am getting response but UI is not updating. Is there anything wrong in my HTML file?

### orderlist.html

```
<html> 
<body> 
    <div class="scrollit" style="overflow-y:auto;height:350px;"> 
        <table class="table table-bordered">     
            <tr  *ngFor="let ord of AllData.orderList;let i=index">        
                <td> <a> {{ord.orderList.order_ID}} </a></td>
            </tr>  
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### orderlist.ts

```
import{Component,OnInit, Input} from'@angular/core';
import {RootObject}from'./orderlist'; 
import{OrderService}from'../OrderLists/service/OrderLists.service';

@Component({
    selector:'my-order',
    templateUrl:'./order.component.html',
    providers:[OrderService]
})

export class OrderComponent implements OnInit{
    ngOnInit(){
    this. OrderRequest();
      }

        public AllData:RootObject[] =[];
        LocalStorageLoginValue:string; //For localStorage Value
        constructor(private orderservice:OrderService){}
        OrderRequest() {
            let shop_ID = this.shop_ID;
            this.orderservice.OrderService(shop_ID)
            .subscribe(
                data =>
                {
                    this.AllData=data
                    console.log(this.AllData);
                },
                error =>alert(error),
                () =>console.log(this.AllData), 
            )
        }
    }
```

---

### orderlistModelClass.ts

```
export interface RootObject {
    status_code: string;
    status_message: string;
    orderList: OrderList[];
    orderSize: number;
}

export interface OrderList {
    address: Address;
    order: Order[];
    user_ID: string;
    timeStamp: number;
    order_ID: string;
    total_Amount: number;
}

export  interface Order {
    product_Name: string;
    price: string;
    product_ID: string;
    units: string;
    qty: string;
    order_Active: boolean;
}

export  interface Address {
    area?: string;
    city?: string;
    landmark?: string;
    house_No?: string;
    locality?: string;
    pinCode?: string;
}
```

---

**This is my JSON Structure:**

[image]

---

```
  {

  "status_code": "200",
  "status_message": "Successfully Authenticated",
  "orderList": [
  {
  "address": {
  "area": null,
  "city": null,
  "landmark": null,
  "house_No": null,
  "locality": null,
  "pinCode": null
  },

  "order": [
  {
 "product_Name": "Super Sugar",
 "price": "400",
 "product_ID": "Product_0",
 "units": "3",
 "qty": "3",
 "order_Active": true
 },
 {
 "product_Name": "Sweet",
 "price": "10",
 "product_ID": "Product_1",
 "units": "5",
 "qty": "3",
 "order_Active": true
 }
 ],

"user_ID": "User_1",
"timeStamp": 1511437347000,
"order_ID": "OID 40D603BCB7",
"total_Amount": 90
},

{
"address": {
"area": null,
"city": null,
"landmark": null,
"house_No": null,
"locality": null,
"pinCode": null
},

"order": [
{
"product_Name": "Super Sugar",
"price": "400",
"product_ID": "Product_0",
"units": "3",
"qty": "3",
"order_Active": true
},
{
"product_Name": "Sweet",
"price": "10",
"product_ID": "Product_1",
"units": "5",
"qty": "3",
"order_Active": true
}
],
"user_ID": "User_1",
"timeStamp": 1511437347000,
"order_ID": "OID 8486300756",
"total_Amount": 90
},

{
"address": {
"area": "Bas1av",
"city": "BLR15",
"landmark": "Op usstop",
"house_No": "#6, 52th Main",
"locality": "Kamalanaga",
"pinCode": "713409"
},

"order": [
{
"product_Name": "sugar",
"price": "30",
"product_ID": "Product_0",
"units": "2",
"qty": "30",
"order_Active": true
},
{
"product_Name": "Rice",
"price": "10",
"product_ID": "Product_1",
"units": "2",
"qty": "3",
"order_Active": true
}
],
"user_ID": "User_0",
"timeStamp": 1511437347000,
"order_ID": "OID D9ECF9C853",
"total_Amount": 90
}
],
"orderSize": 3
}
```

Comment: your code is wrong. kindly send me a your response and update proper coding.
see ngOnInit() ->>inside OrderRequest() and constructor method is there. how is it possible?..

Comment: send your proper code. i will definitely help you.

Comment: The problem might be that AllData.orderList is undefined initially, which already breaks the template. Also AllData is an array of RootObject which seems wrong.

Comment: You can do "AllData[0].orderList" or iterate over AllData using ngFor. But also you need to make sure that AllData.oderList is defined before you receive your data from the service, otherwise Angular will fail. Check the browser console for errors.

Comment: can I iterate both  the array(AllData[ ] and orderList[ ]) using  ngFor in my Html page? OR I should use for loop in my orderComponent page

Comment: Based on your JSON you should not define AllData as an array of RootObject but simply as a RootObject reference. In ngOnInit you then do this.AllData = new RootRecord() or, alternatively, surround the ngFor in your template with an ngIf="AllData", to make sure you don't run in to problems when AllData is undefined in the beginning.

Comment: still its not working

Comment: can you share JSON format as string here, so i can fix this issue quickly.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, please declare model in the *ngIf then start iteration otherwise after DOM loaded iteration will break because `AllData` not declared before html loaded.

```
   <table *ngIf="AllData" class="table table-bordered">     
        <tr  *ngFor="let ord of AllData.orderList;let i=index">        
            <td> <a> {{ord.order['order_ID']}} </a></td>
        </tr>  
    </table>
```